# Codeception- "Failed asserting that two strings are equal." when using $I->canSeeInField

Tags: codeception

I am going to a field, entering text, saving it, then going back to verify the value is still in the field.

$I->waitForText is not working.  Not sure why.  I am trying the following but getting the error below:

$I->canSeeInField("//form[@id='Foo']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/textarea", "123");

```
Sorry, I couldn't see in field "//form[@id='Foo']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/textarea","123":Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WebDriver, you can just debug your page using makeScreenshot()
You can just use:

```
$value = $I->grabFromField('//form[@id='Foo']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/textarea');
```

and fill other fill with your value:

```
$I->fillField('#your_field_id', $value);
```

and than, just make a screenshot:

```
$I->makeScreenshot('name_of_your_screenshot');
```

Now check your debug folder with your image.